# How can I use spyOn in Jasmine to capture the request data sent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have a function that makes a jquery ajax call like so:

```
function update() {
    var data = {
        val1: "val1",
        val2: "val2"
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/test_url",
        type: "POST",
        data: data
    });
}
```

How can I use the spyOn() method to capture the value of "data", which is passed in on the $.ajax call?

I'm using this, but the value of options does not have data.

```
it('expects getListById to send success message', function(done) {
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function(options) {
        console.log(options);
    });

    // Call the ajax function.
    update();
});
```

Here is the console.log:

```
{
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "json",
    "parse": true,
    "url": "http://example.com/test_url",
    "emulateHTTP": false,
    "emulateJSON": false
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to call `update` in your test, where do you call it?

Comment: I tried your code on [tryJasmine](http://tryjasmine.com) and it works for me. Note that in your real test when spying on `$.ajax` you intercept ALL ajax calls made after that. So there might be a call you don't notice to happen and you catch it in fakeCall handler

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I don't get the "data" field back in the options variable.